# python - how to replace all link tags in html with an <em> tag?

Tags: python, html-parsing

I have a routine that converts a long article string into a shorted summary in PHP but rather than do this at page render I'd like to store the summary in a database.

I have everything all sorted out except for replacing link tags with a `<em>text</em>`. I don't want to use beautiful soup for this, I'd rather some simple regex replace if possible, or perhaps another function of HTMLParser (I couldn't find anything after Googling for a while).

Here's what I have currently:

```
import HTMLParser, string, re

tag_end_re = re.compile(r'(\w+)[^>]*>')
entity_end_re = re.compile(r'(\w+;)')

class StrippingParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

    # These are the HTML tags that we will leave intact
    valid_tags = ('a')

    from htmlentitydefs import entitydefs # replace entitydefs from sgmllib

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.result = ""
        self.endTagList = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data:
            self.result = self.result + data

    def handle_charref(self, name):
        self.result = "%s&#%s;" % (self.result, name)

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        if self.entitydefs.has_key(name): 
            x = ';'
        else:
            # this breaks unstandard entities that end with ';'
            x = ''
        self.result = "%s&%s%s" % (self.result, name, x)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        """ Delete all tags except for legal ones """
        if tag in self.valid_tags:       
            self.result = self.result + '<' + tag
            for k, v in attrs:
                if string.lower(k[0:2]) != 'on' and string.lower(v[0:10]) != 'javascript':
                    self.result = '%s %s="%s"' % (self.result, k, v)
            endTag = '</%s>' % tag
            self.endTagList.insert(0,endTag)    
            self.result = self.result + '>'

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag in self.valid_tags:
            self.result = "%s</%s>" % (self.result, tag)
            remTag = '</%s>' % tag
            self.endTagList.remove(remTag)

    def cleanup(self):
        """ Append missing closing tags """
        for j in range(len(self.endTagList)):
                self.result = self.result + self.endTagList[j]    


def strip(s):
    """ Strip illegal HTML tags from string s """
    parser = StrippingParser()
    parser.feed(s)
    parser.close()
    parser.cleanup()
    return parser.result


def truncate_html(string, length, ellipsis='...'):
    """Truncate HTML string, preserving tag structure and character entities."""
    length = int(length)
    output_length = 0
    i = 0
    pending_close_tags = {}

    while output_length < length and i < len(string):
        c = string[i]

        if c == '<':
            # probably some kind of tag
            if i in pending_close_tags:
                # just pop and skip if it's closing tag we already knew about
                i += len(pending_close_tags.pop(i))
            else:
                # else maybe add tag
                i += 1
                match = tag_end_re.match(string[i:])
                if match:
                    tag = match.groups()[0]
                    i += match.end()

                    # save the end tag for possible later use if there is one
                    match = re.search(r'(</' + tag + '[^>]*>)', string[i:], re.IGNORECASE)
                    if match:
                        pending_close_tags[i + match.start()] = match.groups()[0]
                else:
                    output_length += 1 # some kind of garbage, but count it in

        elif c == '&':
            # possible character entity, we need to skip it
            i += 1
            match = entity_end_re.match(string[i:])
            if match:
                i += match.end()

            # this is either a weird character or just '&', both count as 1
            output_length += 1
        else:
            # plain old characters

            skip_to = string.find('<', i, i + length)
            if skip_to == -1:
                skip_to = string.find('&', i, i + length)
            if skip_to == -1:
                skip_to = i + length

            # clamp
            delta = min(skip_to - i,
                        length - output_length,
                        len(string) - i)

            output_length += delta
            i += delta

    output = [string[:i]]
    if output_length == length:
        output.append(ellipsis)

    for k in sorted(pending_close_tags.keys()):
        output.append(pending_close_tags[k])

    return "".join(output)


def summarize(contents,length):
    summary = strip(contents)
    summary = truncate_html(summary,length)
    return summary
```

Calling `summarize('my long text with <a href="" target="_blank">links</a>',400)` currently returns a 400 character (excluding html tags) containing links. I need help replacing those links with  tags.

Comment: Why *not* use BeautifulSoup? BS makes the task *trivial*.

Comment: Can you provide an example of some HTML before and after the desired tag replacement, so that we do not have to interpret your desires from all of that code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex for this:

```
import re
'<em>' + re.search(r'<a.+>(.+)</a>',r'my long text with <a href="" target="_blank">links</a>').group(1) + '</em>'
```